# ERROR TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.combineLatest is not a function

Tags: angular, observable, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Angular 5.2 and Rxjs 5.6-forward-compat.3.

I'm trying to combine two Firestore collections and I think the issue is related to import, but I've tried all possible combinations and options so I'm not sure.

```
Here is the code:`IMPORTS: 
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/combineLatest';

Here is my observable:
getActiveMedicationandCompliance(start: any): Observable<any[]> {
    const email = this.authService.getLoginUserid();
    const userDoc = this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${email}`);

    return userDoc
      .collection<any>(collection.MY_MEDICATION_CABINET, ref =>
        ref.where('active', '==', true).orderBy('medicationName', 'asc')
      )
      .snapshotChanges()
      .map(changes => {
        return changes.map(action => {
          let data = action.payload.doc.data();
          data.id = action.payload.doc.id;
          return userDoc
            .collection<any>(collection.MY_MEDICATION_COMPLIANCE, ref =>
              ref
                .where('medicationCabinetId', '==', data.id)
                .where('createdDate', '>=', start)
                .orderBy('createdDate', 'asc')
            )
            .snapshotChanges()
            .map(changes => {
              changes.map(action => {
                const dataCompliance = action.payload.doc.data();
                dataCompliance.id = action.payload.doc.id;
                return (data = Object.assign(
                  {},
                  { ...dataCompliance, ...data }
                ));
              });
            });
        });
      })
      .mergeMap(observables => Observable.combineLatest(observables));
  }
`
```

Answer (score 0):

combineLatest is not an operator, but part of the observable import:

```
import 'rxjs/observable/combineLatest';
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but...already tried, also tried import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/observable/combineLatest';.

Comment: No, the same. I even tried another version of the observable, with value changes instead of snapshot just for the try, but no changes there either. Could it be my rxjs version? I do not won't to downgrade since I'm planning to upgrade to A V6 soon.

Comment: Is the problem recreatable in stackblitz?

Comment: Unfort not...but do U see anything wrong in my code? I believe I have done everything correct and actually since I'm using FS I think my (stupid) wa would be just to duplicate data, even if I hate it...

Comment: I don't see anything wrong tbh, my best guess is a build system related problem, my advice is to upgrade rxjs.